# Return type from function not inferred on TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I don't know exactly how to put the right terms here, so forgive me if I call things by the wrong name. I have this function below (or at least a subset of it for this example):

```ts
interface Definition {
  props?: { type: string } | ((originalValue: string) => ({ type: string }))
}

function example(definition: Definition) {
  return definition // for the sake of the example let's keep it simple
}
```

When using this function, if I try to provide the `props` argument as a plain object type, the type inference works very well and if I put something that doesn't pertain there I get a TS error, as I expect. However, if I provide the callback it doesn't work as I expected.

If I provide an object:

```ts
example({
  props: { type: '', whateverIsNotThereAndShouldError: 1 } // this makes TS complain, as intended
})
```

However, if I try to do the same with a callback:

```ts
example({
  props: type => ({ type, whateverIsNotThereAndShouldError: 1 }), // no error
})
```

In this usage above, TS recognises the type apparently (the type looks right when having the mouse pointer over `props`) but the bogus element on the object is not pointed and code completion is not triggered. I thought initially this was a VSCode thing, but then it is reproducible on TS Playground.

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIRqYZgHsTIDeAUMsgA5S7kDOA-AFxHJgCe5ETNYUoA5sgC+yAD7IAFONy8+oOABsAagoCunZN14g+ASmQBeAHwTCLdus38hOncUHFiMFSAQ58yCAA84AW3LyIcQATDCw3ECZ0TBBsPBA9EjIoCDAVKAIQ6Nj3AHoc5BhpFgALFBo4AGsUXBgSlC9ffxQAsAByGmQqiHJkbA1gPwC7BwbBwMSKKlomUzYOJlbWgBpkAHdiuEgAN2gASRoAOVwwABVS5IBBECCAZWLcFXkggFEoKigmAEYhFbzkOA6Xg4rggQTstmIoya4gmlGoNCYW1UKCMJjM82QSPkahW602EB2UH2R1O5wgV1u90eLze0i+1l++TozPBQA)

Is this an intended behaviour? Can I do something to keep the TS advantages in the second case without having to explicitly cast the type?

Answer (score 0):

that's expected behavior and is programmed to look like that

there is basically no way to fulfill your intention

this will also apply to most types of object